# Excel does not close

Tags: c#, excel

My problem is that I have a program that reads data from an Excel sheet .xlsb, but when the Excel file is open, then it asks me to save. Why?

```
 async Task<bool> ReadVariable()
        {
            bool succeeded = false;
            while (!succeeded)
            {
                
                //open file excel using microsoft dll
                Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
                

                //open workbook
                Workbook wk = app.Workbooks.Open(excelpath, ReadOnly : true);
                //get first sheet
                Worksheet sh = wk.Worksheets[1];
                //get cell
                // Cells[unten/rechts] Example: [1,2] = B1 
                var day1tag = sh.Cells[27, 2].Value.ToString();
                exceltest1.Text = day1tag;
              
                var day1früh = sh.Cells[26, 2].Value.ToString();
                Day24oee24.Text = day1früh;


               
                app.DisplayAlerts = false;
                wk.Close(SaveChanges : false);
                app.Quit();

                await Task.Delay(15000);
                //await Task.Delay(108000000);
            }
            return succeeded;
        }
```

Comment: In my small tests, using the posted code, I was never given a prompt that _” ask me for the save.”_ … Are you sure this is the code that reproduces your claim? In addition, the posted code is an “infinite loop” since `succeeded` is never set to `true`. Please [edit] your question and supply the code that reproduces your issue. Sorry if I am missing something. I suggest you peruse the SO [tour] section as it shows how SO works. The [ask] section may help. In addition, you may find the SO [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In addition to @JohnG]

First, you should put the `app.Quit();` command line out side of the while loop and then do your algorthyms, after that save your workbook with this code;

```
xlWorkbook.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName + ".xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, null, null, null, null, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, null, null, null, null, null);
```

and then use

```
app.Quit();
```

In addition;
After all process zombie excel will be shown on your task manager to solve that I would like to recommend as follow;

Import;

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

To kill zombie excel use this function;

```
private void KillSpecificExcelFileProcess(string excelFileName)
{
    var processes = from p in Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
                    select p;

    foreach (var process in processes)
    {
        if (process.MainWindowTitle == excelFileName)
            process.Kill();
    }
}
```

And call the function as follow; (Interop excels are nameless due to we should use ("").

```
KillSpecificExcelFileProcess("");
```

Comment: Thx you for that  KillSpecificExcelFileProcess(""); this is great :)

Comment: but you understand me wrong , I don’t want it to save,I don't want him to ask me to save anymore

Comment: Then you shouldn't use `wk.Close();` and `app.Quit();` commands.